# Que objeto de java usar para insertar una fecha en un campo timestamp de PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, timestamp

Estoy trabajando con una **base de datos PostgreSQL**, en la cual tengo un campo de tipo **`timestamp`** ya que solo quiero una fecha con su hora (sin time zone).

Para hacer el guardado estoy haciendo uso del objeto **`LocalDateTime`** de Java 8.

La pregunta es, ¿es buena práctica hacerlo usando ese objeto, o habría que hacer uso del objeto **`Date`** del paquete java.sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repasemos las opciones:

- La clase `java.sql.Date`, como su nombre indica, sólo guarda la fecha, pero sin la hora. No debemos confundirla con `java.util.Date`.
- La clase `java.sql.Timestamp` extiende `java.util.Date`, haciéndola más precisa al guardar hasta nanosegundos.

Por tanto la opción pre-Java 8 sería `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Con Java 8 o superior:

La [documentación de PostgreSQL](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html) orienta hacia el uso de LocalDate (para el tipo DATE) y LocalDateTime (Para el tipo TIMESTAMP):

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE columnfoo = 500");
while (rs.next()) {

   LocalDateTime ts = rs.getObject(1, LocalDateTime.class));
   System.out.println(ts);
} 
rs.close();
st.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque no usas la clase Timestamp que también esta en Java, sería lo más correcto

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html

Comment: Gracias por la repsuesta! Pero necesito entender porqué es mejor usar el objeto `Timestamp` en lugar del `LocalDateTime`. Porque por más que leo no consigo entender la solución. Lo que mas se ha acercado hasta ahora ha sido https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627289/what-is-the-most-recommended-way-to-store-time-in-postgresql-using-java, pero tampoco me queda 100% claro.